# Combine method implementations from different classes based on a configuration at run time

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am trying to implement a class that can dispatch the appropriate functionality based off of a configuration given. The design right now looks like this:

```
class TaskDoer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.task_driver = TaskDriverA()

    def do_tasks(self):
        self.task_driver.do_task1()
        self.task_driver.do_task2()
        ...


class TaskDriverA:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task1(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task2(self):
        ...
    
    ...
```

Now I want to implement a new way to do some of the tasks based off of a configuration provided. The new ways to do tasks all fit into the same class called TaskDriverB. The tasks need to be done with a combination of TaskDriverA's methods and TaksDriverB's methods. I could implement the logic to chose the different methods in the TaskDoer like this:

```
class Configuration:
    def __init__(self, way_to_do_task_1_3_5, way_to_do_task_2):
        self.way_to_do_task_1_3_5 = way_to_do_task_1_3_5
        self.way_to_do_task_2 = way_to_do_task_2
        ...


class TaskDoer:
    def __init__(self, configuration):
        self.configuration = configuration
        self.task_driver_a = TaskDriverA(configuration)
        self.task_driver_b = TaskDriverB(configuration)

    def do_tasks(self):
        if (self.configuration.way_to_do_task_1_3_5 == "A")
            self.task_driver_a.do_task1()
        if self.configuration.way_to_do_task_2 == "A":
            self.task_driver_a.do_task2()
        elif self.configuration.way_to_do_task_2 == "B":
            self.task_driver_b.do_task2()
        ...

class TaskDriverA:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task1(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task2(self):
        ...
    
    ...

class TaskDriverB:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task1(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task2(self):
        ...
```

The problem here is that there are many different TaskDoers across the code base and I want to be able to dispatch the tasks more generally. My initial approach to do this was to create a task dispatcher that dispatched the correct task driver method based off the configuration. Like this:

```
class Configuration:
    def __init__(self, way_to_do_task_1_3_5, way_to_do_task_2):
        self.way_to_do_task_1_3_5 = way_to_do_task_1_3_5
        self.way_to_do_task_2 = way_to_do_task_2
        ...


class TaskDoer:
    def __init__(self, configurations):
        self.task_dispatcher = TaskDispatcher(configuration)

    def do_tasks(self):
        self.task_dispatcher.do_task1()
        self.task_dispatcher.do_task2()
        ...

class TaskDriverA:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task1(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task2(self):
        ...
    
    ...

class TaskDriverB:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task1(self):
        ...
    
    def do_task2(self):
        ...
    

class TaskDispatcher:
    def __init__(self, configuration):
        self.configuration = configuration
        self.task_driver_a = TaskDriverA()
        self.task_driver_b = TaskDriverB()
    
    def do_task1():
        if self.configuration.way_to_do_task_1_3_5 == "A":
            self.task_driver_a.do_task1()

    def do_task2():
        if self.configuration.way_to_do_task_2 == "A":
            self.task_driver_a.do_task2()
        elif self.configuration.way_to_do_task_2 == "B":
            self.task_driver_b.do_task2()
            
    ...
```

The problem I found with this approach is that TaskDriverA had a lot of methods while currently TaskDriverB only had a few. So writing the TaskDispatcher felt like just calling TaskDriverAs methods.

```
class TaskDispatcher:

    ...

    def do_task32():
        self.task_driver_a.do_task32()

    def do_task33():
        self.task_driver_a.do_task33()

    def do_task34():
        self.task_driver_a.do_task34()

    def do_task35():
        self.task_driver_a.do_task35()

    ...
```

Although this would work it felt wrong and I thought there must be another way. There will likely be more methods added to TaskDriverB in the future, although I do not think it would ever match A. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me a good pattern that accounts for this design.

Thank you very much

Comment: classes can inherit from other classes. maybe you want to consider this...

Comment: @D.L I do not think inheritance will solve my problem here since I want to be able to use an arbitrary combination of methods from 2 different classes determined at runtime. Can you clarify how you think it would help? Thanks

Comment: the reason that I suggest this is because if you are going to embark upon using an arbitrary combination of methods, the code will get complicated and it would be cleaner 
 (and certainly more common) to inherit.

Comment: I feel like inheritance is all or nothing though. I want to be able to use TaskDriverA or TaskDriverBs methods somewhat seamlessly in TaskDoer. I could implement a super class for all TaskDrivers, and OOP principles probably dictate that I should, but I don't think that will solve my problem overall.